# BehaviourSubject is not re-rendering my template

Tags: html, arrays, angular, rxjs, openlayers

After a couple of days trying different things, the time has come to ask the question at the community.

I am trying to re-render a template in Angular after clicking/selecting a cluster pointer on an openlayers map.

I tried different things like manual change detection, timeouts, ngzone, simple properties with a switchcase, behavioursubject... nothing re-renders

This is a simplified example of my template

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="subject$ | async as result">
            <ng-container *ngIf="result?.length === 0">

              // Show content when there is no marker clicked

            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="result?.length === 1">

              //Show content when there is a marker clicked with 1 item in it

            </ng-container>

            <ng-container *ngIf="result?.length > 1">

              //Show content when there is a marker clicked with more items in it (clustered)

            </ng-container>
        </ng-container
```

Here is the eventlistener who listens to the custom event

```
    @HostListener('window:featureClick', ['$event'])
    onMarkerClick(event: CustomEvent) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if (this.eg?.length > 0) {
            this.eg = [];
        }
        const clickedFeature = event.detail;
        clickedFeature.forEach((feature) => {
            const matching = this.results.find((res: Object) => res.id === feature);
            if (matching) {
                this.eg = [...this.eg, matching]
            }
        });
        this.subject$.next(this.eg);
    }
```

I always get the initial value === 0 even when the BehaviourSubject emitted the correct value that I want. I would suspect that the async pipe would handle this out of the box.

**Update**

This is the custom event after clicking on an openlayers map.

```
        selectSingleClick.on('select', function (event) {
            const ids: number[] = [];
            const features = event?.selected[0]?.getProperties();
            features?.features?.forEach((feat) => {
                const prop = feat?.getProperties();
                ids.push(prop?.ids);
            });
            const featureClickEvent = new CustomEvent('featureClick', {
                detail: ids
            });

            window.dispatchEvent(featureClickEvent);
        });
```

Comment: I think it may happen because of .stopImmediatePropagation(). could you try to check how it behaves without stopping?

Comment: Hey @Andrei, thank you for responding.

When I remove the . stopImmediatePropagation() the event is triggered twice. And then in errors on the .find() of undefined. 

That is another point that I don't understand...

Comment: @VanonckelenDieter do you mean `<ng-container *ngIf="result?.length === 0">` is always rendered? regardless of `subject$` value?

Comment: try to check if the code is being run inside of the ngZone with `NgZone.assertInAngularZone()` static method

Comment: @BennyHalperin yes exactly.

Comment: It's hard to say without a full reproduction example. Are you reassigning the BehaviorSubject? Can you share a full code example?

Comment: @JoepKockelkorn the .next() is the only thing I do with the behavioursubject. I am also subscribing on it in the ngOnInit to just log the value out of it. Which is correctly logged. 

It is also initialized with empty array [] which is correct. 
That all I am doing with it, and the | async pipe.

Comment: my assumption is that these custom events are not handled by NgZone correctly. If the assertion fails, then forcefull running the code in the zone should fix the issue

Comment: @Andrei Yes that could be the case. Can you try a `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after you `next()`?

Comment: @JoepKockelkorn I also tried that, no difference. Is it obliged to be on strategy OnPush then?

Comment: You're already using the `async` pipe which works with `OnPush` so no that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you create a small reproduction scenario on stackblitz?

Comment: @JoepKockelkorn

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xqxsvz?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fsubcomponent.ts,src%2Fmain.ts

This is the closest I can get. And it works here ....

Comment: It might be me, but your stackblitz isn't working. How do I trigger the issues?

Comment: [Got it working here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bmvepy?file=src%2Fsubcomponent.ts), and when I run this it works: `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('featureClick', { detail: { names: ['default'] } }));`

Comment: @JoepKockelkorn that's my point why I am asking. It works in the stackblitz :(

Comment: @VanonckelenDieter please share your full code (full class and full template). There's probably something else causing this behavior that we don't see in the code you shared

Answer (score 0):

After painful days of debugging I realised that we use Custom elements from Angular.

I defined my component in the HTML and also as Custom element, this will give weird behaviour and should never be done.

Thank you all for trying to help me out!